# Set button from timepicker dialog to always in left side?

Tags: java, android, android-tv

How to make button of timepicker dialog can change positioned? This dialog cant use by pad remote tv, i want button of this dialog can get focus from pad remote tv.
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

try to set timepicker on constraint layout and customable drag or parent on side screen

Comment: how to custom timepickerdialog?